# Issue with json 1.8.1 gem in rails app on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to configure my server for hosting my rails app. Getting this error

```
An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.

Raw process output:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

I am using RVM and migrated from version 1.9.1 to 2.1.2 of ruby. Any pointers would greatly help. Going mad from last 2 days to set up the server

Comment: you can see the output here http://api.getaplan.sitforsat.com/

Please help, its production server and I need to get it up.

Comment: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9444 -- related? It says near the bottom: `You need to cleanup vendor/bundle folder(like rm -r) and bundle install.` Make sure you have a backup though.

Comment: And your logs mention 1.9.3p484. How come?

Comment: IT seems something got messed with rvm . Beacuse we see 2.0.2 in log and later on 1.9.3. 
Try cleaning the gems in rvm set
Please go through this links. It might help you
[link](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems)

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732363/web-application-could-not-be-started-passenger-error-apache2-referencing-non)

Comment: try running server with `bundle exec rails s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided it seems that the ruby version being used doesn't match up with the version identified in the gemset directory. Perhaps [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049966/how-to-downgrade-application-from-ruby-2-0-0-to-1-9-3) will shed some more light.

1) Install new version of Ruby
2) Either set it as the default Ruby, or create a `.ruby-version` file specifying which Ruby version you wish to use in your project
3) Navigate to the project directory and type `ruby -v` to verify the version being used is the correct one
4) Install gems using bundler. You might want to create a separate gemset for this project just to keep things clean and segregated
5) Determine the correct configuration between your HTTP server and Phusion Passenger. Are you using Apache or nginx? Both require you to set the ruby version somewhere and it needs to [point to your new Ruby installation](https://coderwall.com/p/qh1giq) (link uses nginx as an example).

Now you have a new version of Ruby installed and both local command line execution uses it as well as Phusion Passenger. Restart your server and see if it works. If it doesn't, you'll need to provide step-by-step details for me to help further.

Answer (score 2):

try this out:

try running server with `bundle exec rails s`

OR

```
   remove the .bundle/ directory and re-bundle with rm -rf .bundle/ && then bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error. Rails also threw a segmentation fault & core dump. Clobbering my Gemfile.lock and re-running bundle install did the trick:

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle install
```