# Ubuntu Rake command causes segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake

I am trying to setup a rails project and I have to use the `rake db:create` command to create a database. However using this command causes a Segmentation Fault bug with this error:

```
/home/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/ext/parser.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

However when I run the command `bin/rake db:create` I do not get a segmentation fault. I have googled and could not find the reason for this, does anyone know what the cause of this problem is? Is this a serious problem?

After further testing, this seems to be a problem with the `rake` command. Still not sure what is causing this.

**EDIT**
Running the `which -a rake` command gives

```
/home/steven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake
/home/steven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake
/usr/local/bin/rake
```

Running the `which ruby` gives

```
/home/steven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This page looks like it has the answer: you need to reload/reinstall ruby.

[Issue with json 1.8.1 gem in rails app on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493072/issue-with-json-1-8-1-gem-in-rails-app-on-production)

From what you've said above, I can see that you're using rvm. It looks like the gemset for the default rake is ruby-2.2.1, but there's an error involving ruby 1.9.3p484. That's a problem

Let's assume you want to use ruby 1.9.3p484 for your project. From the project directory, run `rvm use 1.9.3p484` and it should switch the PATH variable to set things right.

To see more details about which rake executable you're using, and what's available, and the order of directories Ubuntu searches for a rake executable, you can use

- `which -a rake` -> list all possible rake executables on your PATH
- `echo $PATH` -> show the PATH variable, which has all the directories Ubuntu searches
- `which rake` -> show the rake used by default

Now, the reason `bin/rake db:create` works is because it's the right version of ruby. To set things right, you need to do the rvm use command.

For me, the correct rvm gemset is automatically switched to when I cd to the rails directory. I forget exactly how this works on Ubuntu, but I do know one clue: you need to be in a login shell. You can type `su - steven` to switch to a login shell, but in the Gnome Terminal preferences there's probably something about making sure you're in a login shell.

If you're already in a login shell but it's not working, you could also add

`export PATH=/home/steven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3p484/bin:$PATH`

to the `/home/steven/.bashrc` and/or the `/home/steven/.bash_profile` file (I can never remember which).

There are a lot of reasons why this wouldn't work though, so feel free to comment with more details or update your question and I'll see if I can offer more ideas.
 - List item

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I do not have Ruby 1.9.3 installed using RVM. So I do not understand why the error is referencing 1.9.3. Would reinstalling ruby fix the problem? If so, do you know the commands to do so?

Comment: @Steven It's too hard to answer anything else unless you edit your answer to include the output of `which -a rake` and `which ruby`.

Comment: @Steven OK, so assuming `/usr/local/bin/ruby -v` isn't 1.9.3p484, it looks like it's possible to have the wrong version of ruby reloaded. I added a link to my answer with more details.

Comment: Reinstalling ruby fixed the problem!